# Import could not be resolved from source VSCode Python Windows

Tags: python, windows, import, pip, rabbitmq

I currently have this basic rabbitMQ publisher code from a tutorial for python on windows

```py
import pika

connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
channel = connection.channel()

channel.queue_declare(queue='my_queue')

messages = [
    "Hello from Message 1",
    "Greetings from Message 2",
    "Testing Message 3",
]

for message in messages:
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='my_queue', body=message)
    print(f"Sent message: {message}")

connection.close()
```

The problem is that import pika give me the error "Import 'pika' could not be resolved from source"

I have no idea what the issue could be. I installed it with `pip install pika` and pika also shows up when I do `pip list` HOWEVER `pip list` doesn't show quite a lot of modules that i installed with pip before and that are still currently working like for example pywin32. I'm not sure what that could mean. My programs are still working just fine, all modules work as I'd expect, except for this rabbitMQ program of course. There it just says modules not found.

Maybe another interesting info, when I ctrl+left-click on "pika" in my code it leads me to an **init**.pyi file. I don't really understand what that means but maybe it shows that it is in fact installed?

Would love to get some help on this topic, no idea where to start. I couldn't figure it out with similar solutions online.

Answer (score 0):

the problem might be with some weird compability with vscode itself, you should first of all look for the debugger it's using, you can also try executing your script from the normal terminal and see how that goes

Comment: Executing script from the normal terminal doesn't do anything either. Same error. Not sure what you mean by "look for the debugger it's using". If i knew where my modules are installed then i could maybe manually put the pika files there. I looked into the pip list command again and it seems like it really does put the modules somewhere else because i was able to install modules again that already existed and then they showed up with the command. If I uninstalled them they still worked normally because pip apparently just installed them at some random place that isn't used

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution to my problem. It might've been obvious to others but it's the first time i had to manually install something so I had no clue where to start and for some reason no one online points out where the libraries are in python.

What I did was download the original files from the github repo for pika and put it directly into my library folder.

For anyone else who has this problem:

1. Find your python folder (wherever you installed that, maybe AppData\Local\Programs\Python
2. Go to your python version (for me it's the Python311 folder)
3. Lib -> site-packages
4. Put the files needed for the import in there and it should work

At least that's what fixed it for me. My pip seems to install it somewhere else. I have no idea why but doesn't matter for now.